# Canvas undo operation not working - how to?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to perform a undo operation on my paint app in android studio.I am using a arraylist where previous path will store and than performing the undo operation but this operation not removing each path one by one,it delete the whole image after the arraylist size become zero.

Comment: public void setPathColor(int color) {
        paint.setColor(color);
    }
    public void onClickUndo () {
        int a;
        if (paths.size()>0)
        {
           // undonePaths.add(paths.remove(paths.size()-1));
            paths.remove(paths.size()-1);
        }
        else
        {

        }

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with canvas, where I had to draw and remove few lines very fast.
one of the stable solution for canvas view,I got when I started using Bitmap to draw. Without Bitmap you screen might get clear randomly.

Check this out link on drawing using Android  [Canvas drawing](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/unit-5-advanced-graphics-and-views/lesson-11-canvas/11-1-c-the-canvas-class/11-1-c-the-canvas-class.html)